# send ByteArray from flex to java

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, jakarta-ee, arrays, flex4.5

The scenario is to capture image from webcam and to store image into the DB, I am using flex at the client-side, I am using Java at the server side, following is my flex code

```
var jpg_binary:ByteArray = snap.getPixels(snap.rect);
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../saveProfileImage.htm");
var urlVars : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
request.requestHeaders.push(header);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlVars.image = jpg_binary;
urlVars.resourceId = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters["id"];
urlVars.resourceName= FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters["type"]; 
request.data = urlVars;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
trace ("sending pic to htm");
loader.load(request);
Alert.show("Uploaded Successfully");
```

now i need help in writing the java part of it, i mean how to receive the byteArray from the request object.

Comment: should i use the **Request Header** as `("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");` as i am sending multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use request's [getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream%28%29)

```
InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
int readBytes = 0;
int len = request.getContentLength();
byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
    // your code here.
}
```

Comment: where to specify param name as i am sending multiple parameters, parameter containing my byte array is "image"